# How can I extract a sub matrix of order 4*4 from four 2*2 corner blocks of a 6*6 matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Let

```
mat = RandomInteger[10, {6, 6}]; 
mat // MatrixForm
```

I can access elements as follows

```
  b={{mat[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]]}, {mat[[1 ;; 2, 5 ;; 6]]},
mat[[5 ;; 6, 1 ;; 2]], mat[[5 ;; 6, 5 ;; 6]]} // MatrixForm
```

but doesn't appear in the 2*2 blocks form for the 4*4 sub matrix. is it possible to get that 4*4 sub matrix from here?

I tried Take (Drop) to get a sub matrix from 4*4 blocks which is quite easy

```
Take[mat, {3, 6}, {3, 6}] // MatrixForm
```

or

```
Take[mat, {1, 4}, {1, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

but not sure if Take can be used to extract 4*4 made up of corner four 2*2 blocks.

Comment: ``mat[[{1, 2, -2, -1}, {1, 2, -2, -1}]]``

Comment: @Domen, perfect. Thanks. Now I tried this too mat[[{1, 2, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 5, 6}]] // MatrixForm

Comment: also `Drop[mat,3;;-3,3;;-3]`